# setting selected value as undefined in angualrjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularjs ng-options and ng-model directives in my view to set the select option and get notified when dropdown option is selected or changed. I am also adding extra empty option so that user can deselect this and for that I want value in ng-model expression to be undefined. Is there any way to do that ? I tried adding value=="{{undefined}}" but that takes out the empty option totally.

Here is the plunker example where if I select the empty option then data.model should be undefined but here it is coming as null.

https://plnkr.co/edit/d9Jzs4YgqpWHbOxonwa3?p=preview

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-select-ngvalue-production</title>


  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>




    </head>
    <body ng-app="ngvalueSelect">
      <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
      <form name="myForm">
        <label for="ngvalueselect"> ngvalue select: </label>
        <select size="6" name="ngvalueselect" ng-model="data.model" multiple>

          <option label='' value="{{undefined}}"/>
          <option ng-repeat="option in data.availableOptions" ng-value="option.value">{{option.name}}</option>

        </select>
      </form>
      <hr>
      <pre>model = {{data.model === undefined | json}}</pre><br/>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Corresponding app.js is

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('ngvalueSelect', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
     model: null,
     availableOptions: [
          {value: 'myString', name: 'string'},
          {value: 1, name: 'integer'},
          {value: true, name: 'boolean'},
          {value: null, name: 'null'},
          {value: {prop: 'value'}, name: 'object'},
          {value: ['a'], name: 'array'}
     ]
    };
 }]);
})(window.angular);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code:

1. Your dropdown allows multiple select thanks to the `multiple` attribute. This means that your model stores array of selections. The value you are looking for is one of the elements of the array, but in your code you are comparing `undefined` to the whole array.
2. Your additional option should use `ng-value` instead of `value` attribute. You don't need to write is as separate option, you can add it to `availableOptions` object  (as `{value: undefined, name: ''}`).

Here is the updated plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/RXUlW6P7DX2wPZOazwe8?p=preview